# Js Convert Object To Number Return Nan

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For a customer, I want to tell them that if the price of the products in the current currency they have active is equal to zero, to change their currency and not be able to add to the shopping cart, but no matter what, I try to get the data inside the amount. Nan is coming back

My Html Code

```js
var priceProduct = document.getElementById('itemprice').lastChild;
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
  if(priceProduct == 0) {
   //The rest of the code
  } else {
   //The rest of the code
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span id="itemprice"><span class="sym-curr">$</span>0.00</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="button-cart" class="product-add-to-basket">
  <span class="add-to-cart-text">add To cart</span>
</button>
```

Comment: What does debugging give you for `priceProduct`?  What *type* is parseProduct?   `.lastChild()` will *always* give you a DOM node - you can't `parseInt` a DOM node (well, you can, it will give you NaN)...  you need to get the text value from the DOM node.

Comment: the debugging retun 0.00 and its object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
var priceProduct = document.getElementById('itemprice').lastChild
```

`.lastcChild` will always give you a DOM node, in this case a text node.

To get the text node, use `node.textContent`  (or node.innerText, differences are subtle).

You can then parse this to an int, to compare with 0, or you can compare with a string directly:

```js
var priceProduct = document.getElementById('itemprice').lastChild.textContent;
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
  if (priceProduct === "0.00") {
   //The rest of the code
   console.log("no cost");
  } else {
   //The rest of the code
   console.log("cost to be calculated");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span id="itemprice"><span class="sym-curr">$</span>0.00</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="button-cart" class="product-add-to-basket">
  <span class="add-to-cart-text">add To cart</span>
</button>
```

One issue you have here is that the value is `0.00` - parsing to an int will give `0` - if you value was actually `0.10` then `parseInt("0.10")` will also give "0" - your values are decimals not ints.